# custom authorize attribute which returns ControllerName + ActionName

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I have custom AuthorizeAttribute as here : [Handling session timeout in ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238854/handling-session-timeout-in-ajax-calls)
It works great. But **LogOn** Action of the **Account** Controller has returnURL parameter in **ASP.NET MVC**. After LogON it returns to last page(returnURL). And now i want to to return data as below if  :

```
if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {

    filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                        {
                            Data = new
                            {
                                // put whatever data you want which will be sent    
                                // to the client    
                                message = "/Account/LogON/?returnUrl=" + filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName + "/" + filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName
                            },
                            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                        }; 
                 }
           }
```

But you can see here that it returns ActionName which called by **ajax**.But I want to return base ActionName. Please advice me. I have some ideas as hidden value or get ActionName from windows.location with javascript. but i think it is not good idea.
Ask question if you will not understand my question

Comment: What do you mean under base action name?

Comment: lets say i am in List Action of Products Controller. And a call GetAjax Action of Products Controller with ajax. And i want to receive /Products/List not /Products/GetAjax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [HttpRequest.UrlReferrer Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx)