# To redirect the user to login page automatically instead of crash on page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, forms-authentication, jquery-ajaxq

In our ASP.NET MVC Application, when session get timed out , page give crash on  components where we have Jquery AJAX calls, however if we manually load the page it log out and redirect to login page.

We want user to redirect to login page automatically when session get expired, we are using form authentication and have a CustomPrincipal defined.

Comment: Might be a duplicate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238854/handling-session-timeout-in-ajax-calls

Comment: Thanks @SainPradeep, but I want to log out the user and want to do it on application level not on Individual controller.

Comment: You can use a global Custom filter for this(AuthorizeFilter or ActionFilter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

insert following code in **global.asax**

```
    public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
       public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
       {
          if (HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionId"] == null)
           {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/Login");
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
      }
    }
```

and in **every controller** call this attribute as following

```
   [SolutionName.MvcApplication.SessionExpire]
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
   }
```