# How can I extend the Authorize attribute's logic in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, authorize-attribute

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core MVC application and I want to be able to better handle what happens when an unauthenticated user runs an action through AJAX.

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10866348/12300287) that essentially extends the `Authorize` attribute's logic and sets an AJAX request's status code to `401` when user is no longer authenticated. The status code is returned to a global AJAX error handler and the appropriate action can be performed.

I'm trying to create the attribute in Core 3.1 but I cannot find a way to first run the base logic of the filter. `base.OnAuthorization` method is not there. I specifically don't want to rewrite the `Authorize` attribute's functionality - only to extend it.

How can I extend the `Authorize` attribute's logic in Core 3.1?

The authorize attribute I'm writing:

```
public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(context); //method does not exist
        OnAjaxAuthorization(context);
    }

    internal void OnAjaxAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just as a side note, I was thinking of writing a `ActionFilterAttribute` to run the additional code instead, but I can't do that because the `Authorize` attribute always runs first.

Comment: The OnAuthorization is not defined, try to remove it.  And why not use the method of accepted solutions?

Comment: I understand it's not defined but I'm wondering is there any other way to run the base logic of the `Authorize` attribute so I can extend it? As for the accepted answer, I guess it's the same issue. I'm not sure how to get it working with Core 3.1. I try to add the attribute but it just gets skipped.

Comment: The link you provided applies to traditional Asp.net MVC application, instead of Asp.net core 3.1.  And in asp.net core there doesn't have the ISAjaxRequest() method, to check whether the request is call through the Ajax method, you can add a custom property in the request header or requese body, and set it as “IsAjaxRequired”. In the custom authorization attribute, you can get this property and check whether the request is a Ajax request or not, then do something.

Comment: In asp.net core 3.1 application to create custom Authorization attributes, you can check the following links: [Link 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-authorization-attributes), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464359/how-do-you-create-a-custom-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-core) and [link 3](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-override-customauthorization-class-in-net-core/)